# Android - Compute times a two numbers appear in cell number

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

Could anyone help me. I am trying to compute the number of times certain numbers appear in a table layout row - vertically and Horizontally, in other words. I would like to fill an array of numbers between say (4 and 5) to make it so that the number say 4 appears only 4times and 5 only twice (vertically & Horizontally) in say 6 * 6..take note

**How can I work with any of this?**

```
public boolean hasRepeatedNumbers(int[] x) {  
        int[] y = new int[x.length];   
            System.arraycopy(x, 0, y, 0, y.length);   
        Array.sort(y);  
        int i;  
        for (i = 1; i < y.length; i++) {  
            if (y[i] == y[i-1]) return true;  
        }  
    return false;  
   }
```

or

```
private int[] calculateUsedCells(int x, int y) {  
   int c[] = new int[2];  
   // horizontal  
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {   
       if (i == y)  
          continue;  
       int t = getCell(x, i);  
       if (t != 0)  
          c[t - 1] = t;  
   }
 }
```

Any advice would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking an int array and increase the element in the array at index of the value in the cell, at the end check the values in the array. You will get the number of times each number appeared.

Ex:
Number 4 has appeared in 1, 2, 5, 6 cells

```
array[content of the cell]++;
```

So at the end array[4] gives the number of times 4 appeared.